# How to clear cells if criteria met after copying to new worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, copy, cell

I want to clear the value in D34:155 if criteria value "Fælles" or "Lagt ud" is in the cell and the text is NOT bold.

I do not have much coding experience yet. I have tried some clear ranges and delete which didn't work.
With this last code it just seems like it clears random places in the range.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

A = Worksheets("Stig Okt").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 34 To A
If Worksheets("Stig Okt").Cells(i, 4).Font.Bold = False And Cells(i, 4).Value = "Fælles" Then
    Worksheets("Stig Okt").Rows(i).Columns("A:H").Copy
    Worksheets("Laura Okt").Activate
    b = Worksheets("Laura Okt").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Laura Okt").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

If Worksheets("Stig Okt").Cells(i, 4).Font.Bold = False And Cells(i, 4).Value = "Lagt ud" Then
    Worksheets("Stig Okt").Rows(i).Columns("A:H").Copy
    Worksheets("Laura Okt").Activate
    b = Worksheets("Laura Okt").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Laura Okt").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

If Worksheets("Laura Okt").Cells(i, 4).Value = "Fælles" And Cells(i, 4).Font.Bold = False Then
    Worksheets("Laura Okt").Cells(i, 4).Clear
ElseIf Worksheets("Laura Okt").Cells(i, 4).Value = "Lagt ud" And Cells(i, 4).Font.Bold = False Then
    Worksheets("Laura Okt").Cells(i, 4).Clear
End If
Next
Worksheets("Stig Okt").Activate


End Sub
```

It is the very last part of the code i need help with. Where it says "Clear"
Help is much appreciated. Thank you for taking the time to read through!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid unexpected behaviour, have less typing and make your code more readable) by using an [WITH..END WITH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement) block. For example like this ;

```
Sub process()

  ' scan down sheet "Stig Jan" from 36 to last row
  '   where col D font is NOT bold AND col D value = "Fælles" Or "Lagt Ud"
  '     copy columns "A:H" to sheet "Laura Jan", appending to existing records
  '     clear col D on "Laura Jan"
  '   where col N font is NOT bold and col N value = "Fælles" Or "Lagt Ud"
  '     copy columns "K:R" to sheet "Laura Jan", appending to existing records
  '     clear col N on "Laura Jane"

  Dim wsSource, wsTarget As Worksheet
  Dim i, iLastSource, iRowTarget, count As Long
  Dim cell As Range

  Set wsSource = Worksheets("Stig Jan")
  iLastSource = wsSource.cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

  Set wsTarget = Worksheets("Laura Jan")

  count = 0
  With wsSource
    iRowTarget = wsTarget.cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For i = 36 To iLastSource
      ' check col 4 (D) and copy "A:H" to Laura "A:H" last row
      Set cell = .cells(i, 4)
      If cell.Font.Bold = False Then
        If cell.Value = "Fælles" Or cell.Value = "Lagt Ud" Then
          .Rows(i).Columns("A:H").Copy wsTarget.Range("A" & iRowTarget)
          'wsTarget.Range("D" & iRowTarget).ClearContents
          wsTarget.Range("D" & iRowTarget).Interior.Color = vbRed ' replace this line with ClearContent
          iRowTarget = iRowTarget + 1
          count = count + 1
        End If
      End If
    Next

    iRowTarget = wsTarget.cells(Rows.count, 11).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For i = 36 To iLastSource
      ' check col 14 (N) and copy "K:R" to Laura "K:R" last row
      Set cell = .cells(i, 14)
      If cell.Font.Bold = False Then
        If cell.Value = "Fælles" Or cell.Value = "Lagt Ud" Then
          .Rows(i).Columns("K:R").Copy wsTarget.Range("K" & iRowTarget)
          'wsTarget.Range("N" & iRowTarget).ClearContents
          wsTarget.Range("N" & iRowTarget).Interior.Color = vbRed ' replace this line with ClearContent
          iRowTarget = iRowTarget + 1
          count = count + 1
        End If
      End If
    Next
  End With
  MsgBox "Done : " & count & " rows copied"

  End Sub
```

Comment: You have really gone out of your way to help me!

Comment: You have really gone out of your way to help me! I Understand why i was giving you guys a headache. :) I just wanted to make a simple spreadsheet, but then the functions got more advanced and somehow i managed. And then the copy paste stuff annoyed me and suddenly i found myself trying to code. And at this very point i can't comprehend what I have managed to do! This site offcourse deserves 80% of the credit and it wouldnt have been possible without it. But what a journey! And now i need to go take a basics course, so i can actually grasp what it is I have been doing! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you. Note I have corrected my example so that it deletes the cell on the target sheet (Laura) rather than the source (Stig). On piece of advice I would offer is take time to learn how to use the debug facility so that you can single step (F8) your program. Also use debug.print at points in the program where something is not working right.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are seeing random behavior due to the four times in the code above where the Cells property is referenced without a qualification. I believe that when a Cells property reference is not qualified, the default behavior is to use the Cells property of the active spreadsheet at the time the code is executed.

For example the code above shows:

```
If Worksheets("Stig Okt").Cells(i, 4).Font.Bold = False And Cells(i, 4).Value = "Lagt ud" Then
```

But you may actually intend something like:

```
If Worksheets("Stig Okt").Cells(i, 4).Font.Bold = False And Worksheets("Stig Okt").Cells(i, 4).Value = "Lagt ud" Then
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello Geoff, Thank you so much for taking the time to help me! I know the first part of the code works like a charm. It is only the 3. IF function that is troubling.    I tried doing your suggestion the whole way up, however, but now it only copies the 1. of the 3 sugestions which are not bolded. and doesn't clear the 4. coloumn afterwards. It stopped clearing random cells though! :D

Comment: I took another look at the code above, and it occurs to me that the row being cleared on spreadsheet "Laura Okt" is the same row number as the copied row from "Stig Okt". Perhaps you intend to clear the cell in the destination row "Laura Okt" instead, in which case you need to change the variable 'i' to 'b + 1'   when checking and clearing the row on spreadsheet "Laura Okt"

Comment: Yes, that is what i want to do. :) I want to move these columns to the new sheet based on the criteria. Afterwards in the new sheet i want to delete the criteria row only, if not bold font. Thank you for your patience. I am very new to coding! :)